# jQuery unobtrusive validation not working on radio button

Tags: jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have the following markup:

```
<input id="davcardholder-yes" data-val="true" data-val-required="The CustomerDVACardHolder field is required." name="CustomerDVACardHolder" type="radio" value="Yes">
<label for="davcardholder-yes"><span></span>&nbsp; Yes &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</label>
<input id="davcardholder-no" name="CustomerDVACardHolder" type="radio" value="No">
<label for="davcardholder-no"><span></span>&nbsp; No &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</label>
```

And in another place:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The CustomerFirstName field is required." id="CustomerFirstName" name="CustomerFirstName" type="text" value="">
```

jQuery unobtrusive validation is working for the latter, but not the former -- i.e. it's not working for the radio buttons.

It's not a display issue - it's actually allowing the form to submit, and is *not* adding class 'input-validation-error' to the first radio button.

Anyone know what might be causing this to fail? Using jQuery 1.8, jQuery validate 1.11.1 and jQuery unobtrusive (no version). Thanks!